# Why was the etiquette question about queueing for the second time closed?

Tags: discussion

The question [Etiquette for a person who has already queued once](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/14893/8077) seems to be a good question about etiquette, and was received and understood well by the community.

It is asking about the etiquette in the UK when a person has to queue for the second time. Simple as that. To me, that is as good an etiquette question as we can hope for in this stack.

So I would like to ask here, why it was closed as 'unclear what you're asking'? And what would be needed for it to be clearer?

Comment: I agree that this is probably about as good an etiquette question as can be asked on the stack, but is that enough? A "what should I do" or "who is right" question, even if the best possible question of its type, would not be allowed here.

Answer (score 2):

The only questions I can extract from the text are :

> Was my understanding of the etiquette regarding re-queuing wrong in not allowing the woman to be served first?

And :

> Why did she ask the question if she felt entitled to go first?

The first question is asking for validation (which seems okay if it's indeed an etiquette question)

We can't give an answer about the second question as it's trying to read someone's mind.

It needs to be edited to be clearer, maybe add something such as

> **What is the correct etiquette for the first in line in this situation ?**

At the end of the question, then it can probably be reopened.

Comment: If I can make a suggestion to users of this stack (not specifically at you!)... if the edit to make it on topic really is that simple, ***make the edit yourself***. As far as I can tell this was OP's first question here and new users don't always understand how to phrase things appropriately.

Comment: FWIW I've made such an edit now. I think the second question when read in context is rhetorical (it's describing what OP was arguing about with the woman) so I've left that as is.

Answer (score 0):

That last paragraph seems to distract a bit from the actual etiquette question and invites answers or parts of an answer to a "Did I handle it right?". If we look at the second answer on this question it also becomes clear that as it is now, it's not just about the etiquette:

> Assuming your question is "How should I handle this sort of thing politely if it happens again?"

If we were to remove the entire paragraph (about shouting to each other) it's a great question and your answer explains it nicely (which is shown by the upvotes and checkmark).