# Etiquette question about "common gesture" and quality of answers

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-question, questions

I'm talking about this question: [Pointing the index fingers to one another as a way to excuse oneself: is this a common gesture?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/23515/21067)

At first look, I thought this was a mostly valid question, however, after seeing the answers, I think there is a problem with it.

Indeed, the answers seem to be opinion-based and turning into a list of:

> I'm from country X and I do/don't understand this gesture.

I think having a list of such answers is really not interesting for a Q&A site like use. This leads me to think that such a question is primarily opinion-based or, at least, needs some editing to become a good question.

What are your thought? Could we improve the question to make it better? Should we just close it?

If you think the question is fine, what are your thought about the answers (like [this one](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/23525/21067) or [this one](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/23516/21067))? Is this the kind of answer we want? Are they in line with our [good answer faq](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3266/21067)? Should we want them to be more "substential", to use external resources as backup?

Comment: Emojis are not universal to most people like [this answer](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/23517/12962) from avazula. Some people refer to the emoji as an high-five, others like me refer as preying. There is [Emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/) that can help.

Comment: Related: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3019/can-etiquette-questions-be-answered-consistently-with-stack-standards

Answer (score 1):

I think that the question is still valid despite the less than ideal answers. However, I think that the answers from [avazula](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/23517/22086) and [arielCo](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/23528/22086) are of excellent quality and objectivity. Overall, the quantity of lower-quality answers is similar to a lot of the other questions since we got back on HNQ. The only difference in this particular question is that we specifically see "In [my country]" where normally people just say "I would..." and that seems to make the poorer answers stand out. On other "I would" answers we just DV/delete those answers instead of closing the question. At least, that's how I see it.

As for answers that really only state the attitude of the answerer's country, I am on the fence on whether we should or shouldn't delete them. On one hand they seem pretty low quality, even opinion based. OTOH, if we get a number of the more populated countries then we can get a heat-map of what this particular emoji means. We have Italy, UK, China, and USA (I assume that's what "America" means in MonkeyZeus' answer).

I'm not sure if we really want a number of low-quality answers to add up to one [good?] answer. Unless we want to consolidate the answers into a community answer to generate a list of countries.

Comment: So, do you think we should delete the answer that only state "in my country"?

Comment: agreed on the 2 cited answers, but the top-ranked one... IMO, this is *not* answering at all, merely a comment (I made the same kind, OP (avazula?) used it to improve, and move on). Otherwise, we'll end up with 200 "*in my country*" answers...

Comment: @Ælis I've edited my answer to offer my take on those answers

Comment: @OldPadawan the top-ranked answer does provide OP with an answer to their "hidden" question though. Basically seeing the inconsistency shows me it is a huge red flag for miscommunication.

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza : see this edit from OP please -> "*I can't currently accept any of the (very insightful) answers I received, **mostly because they all provide the point of view and personal experience of the author**, and **some of these experiences are conflicting with each other**.*" (emphasis mine). Which brings us back to my comment above = "*Otherwise, we'll end up with 200 "in my country" answers*". OP hasn't received any answer to **their** need. Some points have been raised, but the problem remains. I stick to my comment, the top-rated answer isn't an answer...